# Parsing DCS scripts into lists/dictionaries in python

Tags: parsing, text

I am quite new to python and I am trying to use it (Python 2.7.14) to pull information out of a text file.

When I copy part of the text file as a string and run a search, as so:

```
import re

data = """ATTRIBUTE_INSTANCE NAME="R_MIX_HIHI_LIM"
    {
      VALUE { CV=0 }
    }
    ATTRIBUTE_INSTANCE NAME="R_MIX_LOLO_LIM"
    {
      VALUE { CV=0 }
    }
    ATTRIBUTE_INSTANCE NAME="R_MIX_SP"
    {
      VALUE { CV=0 }
    }
    ATTRIBUTE_INSTANCE NAME="R_VAC_HIHI_LIM"
    {
      VALUE { CV=0 }
    }
    ATTRIBUTE_INSTANCE NAME="R_VAC_LOLO_LIM"
    {
      VALUE { CV=0 }
    }
    ATTRIBUTE_INSTANCE NAME="R_VAC_SP"
    {
      VALUE { CV=0 }
    }
    ATTRIBUTE_INSTANCE NAME="L_RECIRC_TM"
    {
      VALUE { CV="" }
    }
    ATTRIBUTE_INSTANCE NAME="L_RECIRC_TM_SP"
    {
      VALUE { CV="" }
    }"""

regex = re.compile(r"ATTRIBUTE_INSTANCE NAME\=\"([A-Za-z][_A-Za-z]+)")
result = regex.search(data)

for result in regex.findall(data):
    print result
```

I get the output I am seeking. The problem arises when I try to directly search the text file using the following:

```
import re

f_open = open("file.txt", "r")
data = f_open.read()

regex = re.compile(r"ATTRIBUTE_INSTANCE NAME\=\"([A-Za-z][_A-Za-z]+)")
result = regex.search(data)

for result in regex.findall(data):
    print result

f_open.close()
```

My search command no longer outputs anything. This is due to the "open" command adding spaces between all the characters. So instead of:

```
ATTRIBUTE_INSTANCE NAME="R_PRS_CTRL_LM"
{
  VALUE { CV=0 }
}
```

I am getting:

```
     A T T R I B U T E _ I N S T A N C E   N A M E = " R _ P R S _ C T R L _ L M "
     {
         V A L U E   {   C V = 0   }
     }
```

Is there any to make sure my code reads the text file without adding spaces, thus breaking my search function?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The DCS output file is binary. Converting the file fixes the issue.